# R and Azure SQL Database how to get last table created?

Tags: r, azure

I am learning how to connect R notebook and Azure SQL database. I have created my connection with library DBI. I created a table called mtcars from the internal datasets. When I use dblistTables() I get back the tables and a lot of other stuff. How do I get the latest table created? and not all the other stuff?

```
analyst_database_connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                                              Server = "tcp:abc.database.windows.net,1433",
                                              Database = "analyst_database",
                                              UID = "user", PWD = "password")

analyst_database_connection_list_of_tbls <- dbListTables(analyst_database_connection)
dbCreateTable(analyst_database_connection, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbAppendTable(analyst_database_connection, "mtcars", mtcars)


dbListTables(analyst_database_connection)

dbListTables(analyst_database_connection)
```

**This is the result but all I want is the latest table(s) or just the tables and not all the other stuff. What am I doing wrong?**

[image: tables]

Comment: SQL Server has a _lot_ of system tables used internally, rarely do most users ever need to use (or even see) most of them. That aside ... I don't know that we can know when a table was created (I'm not certain if it is even recorded somewhere). BTW, `"ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"` is ancient; `"ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"` is current, and `17` is still actively maintained (and there are some breaking differences between them). There are enough problems with `13` (e.g., TZ, datetimeoffset) that I urge you to update.

Comment: Will do, can you suggest a work around? to get just the tables?

Comment: It seems you may be able to remove a lot based on the presence of upper-case letters, but ... there is really not enough information from `dbListTables(con)` to do easy filtering based on name alone. Perhaps `grep("[_A-Z]", dbListTables(con), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)` could be a start? (It's likely to be too-greedy if you have mixed case table names.) Once you know what tables you need and/or create, there seems little reason to actually list them all. For instance `SELECT * FROM quux` happily fails if your table does not exist, which may be a good-enough indicator.